# why MakeAppx generate 0 kb file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, appx, microsoft-edge-extension, makeappx

I have developed cross browser extension and i want to deploy it on Microsoft store so refer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/getting-started#Publishing

when i generate Appx file of my extension using

```
MakeAppx pack /d E:/extension/CAPPMRoadmapPrint/edgeextension/manifest/Extension /p E:/claity.appx
```

command but it generates 0 kb file namely clarity.appx.

directory structure of my extension

[image]

i didn't understand why it generates 0 kb file or any other way to generate my extension's appx file.

Comment: Paths in Windows are usually written with \ not / so maybe that's why. Otherwise make sure you've followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/blob/master/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages.md) properly.

Comment: i tried both / and \ none of them is working for me

Comment: i followed the exac tutorial you gave but still it generates 0 kb appx file. @wOxxOm

Comment: I can see that you are developing cross browser extension. So did you made the necessary changes for MS Edge in your manifest and other files?

Comment: yes i made that i can show you if you to show my manifist json file